# SFTP: give user access to folder outside home

Tags: linux, chroot, sftp, account-restrictions

I have a machine running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with OpenSSH server installed. I have created a user  with a jailed home account.

When I log in with the user's account, I can only access his home (duh).

In addition to the user's home folder, I would like to give the him read access to a particular partition (`/Volumes/Storage`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to ensure that the chroot that the users is put in has access to the directory by bind mounting into the chroot tree:

```
mount --bind /Volumes/Storage /path/to/chroot
```

The user will also need to have necessary filesystem permissions to read the data on the drive. The easiest way to accomplish this would be to put the user in a supplementary group that has ownership of the files (assuming standard 755 and 644 permissions).

Comment: The /path/to/chroot is that the user his home directory?

In my sshd_config file I set:

ChrootDirectory %h

Comment: @user21670 - No, its the root of the chroot. It can be anywhere inside of the chroot, including the user's home directory.

Comment: and how do I unbind?

never mind: I was able to do it using umount

Comment: To make this permanent (i.e. so it will work after reboot), add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:
`/Volumes/Storage /path/to/chroot none bind 0 0`